# Navigate to a contact from a list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to click on a specific contact and take me to their page. I am not sure how to get the navigator to work. When I click on the contacts list page name, I want it to take me to a viewContact page of that person's information.

```
    class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Contact> _contacts;

  ContactList(this._contacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new _ContactListItem(_contacts[index], onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => viewContact()),
        });
      },

      itemCount: _contacts.length,
    );

  }
}
```

Other option I came up with:

```
class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Contact> _contacts;

  ContactList(this._contacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new _ContactListItem(_contacts[index]);
        Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => viewContact())
        );
      },

      itemCount: _contacts.length,
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: ItemBuilder should be a function

Comment: @Rémi Rousselet So what would that function look like? Im still getting my head around everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think this a duplicate of [Proper page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52286696/proper-page-navigation/)
Can't flag it because the other question doesn't have an upvote or accepted answer.
Pasting my answer here as well.

Here are few things that I can immediately point out (Problems):

- `onPressed` is not available on `ListView.builder()` , you may check
  here:
  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html
- `Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => viewContact())` this won't execute because it is after `return`

Suggestions:

- You might need to wrap your `_ContactListItem()` inside a
  `GestureDetector` and implement an `onTap` callback

Sample Code:

```
class ContactList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Contact> _contacts;

  ContactList(this._contacts);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            //TODO: Insert your navigation logic here
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    ContactView(_contacts[index])));
          },
          child: _ContactListItem(_contacts[index]),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _contacts.length,
    );
  }
}
```

- Another option could be to change the implementation of
  `_ContactListItem()` and may be use a `ListTile` and implement an `onTap` in `ListTile`, you can find it here: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html
- You may also try to implement named routes, here is a tutorial for
  that https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/named-routes/

I hope this was helpful in someway, let me know if I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to have a look on this tutorial since it looks to be exactly what you are trying to achieve : https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

The idea is to redefine a `MaterialRoutePage` inside your page to send specific data.

Here's the example

```
onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => DetailScreen(contact: contact_information),
    ),
  );
},
```

But your `DetailScreen` constructor should take a contact as an argument.

Hope it helps !!